# Parse XML-file on SD-card Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML-file located under sdcard/myFiles. The XML-files my application is going to parse can(and most likely will) have lots of text in them. I've read a lot about XML-parsing but I can't get the grasp of it. Especially not which method(SAX, DOM, etc.) that would suit my application the most.

My XML-files will look like this:

```
<Food>
    <info>Dish.1.</info>
    <info>Ingredients that belongs to dish 1</info>
    <info />
    <info>Dish.2.</info>
    <info>Ingredients that belongs to dish 2</info>
    <info />
    <info>Dish.3.</info>
    <info>Ingredients that belongs to dish 3</info>
</Food>
```

I'm not sure what this kind of xml-layout is called but I don't know where to start when there is no 'hierarchy'. Well, everything that is under Dish.1. belongs to Dish.1. until Dish.2. comes into picture etc. I have to add that the text in the 'Main'-tag will always be Dish.*.  ( * increments by 1)

Ultimately Dish.1. will go into a db-table with (column)rowId: 1, (column)name: Dish.1, (column)ingredients: ingredients that belongs to...

So I will also have to parse the content of tag info to throw it into the correct column.

Any help would be appreciated, and if it's not even possible I would want to know that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to answer my own question but:

Would it be best to just add all of the contents into a String array and then parse the content to send it to the correct column

or should the content parsing be handled at the same time i'm parsing the XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely parse XML from the SD card. I would suggest using a SAX or PullParser if you have lots of data to go through as these will use less memory to parse the data.

However from the example XML you have posted I would suggest brushing up on the XML conventions a bit more, perhaps via a tutorial like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/).

Comment: Actually this is a good page for explaining how to properly nest data so it can easily be parsed [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)